# CefSharp: I want to open my custom keyboard in the ChromiumWebBrowse

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome, cefsharp, on-screen-keyboard

I want to open my own keyboard in the ChromiumWebBrowser. I do not know how to do that. I cannot determine the focus of an Input element. And I only need my own touch keyboard. I use CefSharp.WinForms 83.4.20.0. Windows 7 and Windows 8 , Windows 10

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["touch-events"] = "enabled";
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-usb-keyboard-detect", "1");
Cef.Initialize(settings)
```

This brings up the Windows OnScreen-Keyboard, but I want brings up own keyboard.

Comment: There are no CefSharp specific options for this. Does chrome support disabling the onscreen keyboard on Windows? You can search the chromium source online at https://cs.chromium.org I'd suggest you add some different tags here on stackoverflow and make your question more generic. CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers.

Comment: Unfortunately those tags aren't likely to get you any results. You need something chrome/chromium specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. This code helped to connect my keyboard

browser settings

```
   CefSharpSettings.ShutdownOnExit = true;
   CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
   settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\CEF";
   settings.CefCommandLineArgs["print-preview"]= "disable";
   Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

Keyboard call

```
ScreenKeyboard.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            ScreenKeyboard.Visible = (task.Exception == null && task.Result);
                        }));
```